# How can I fill in missing values in pandas dataframe using conditions on the data?

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

I have a data set of cars and have to train a model to predict the price of the car, but my doubt lies in data cleaning. The following are the columns present in the dataframe car_df:

```
Data columns (total 17 columns):
Id                     53515 non-null int64
Maker                  53515 non-null object
model                  53515 non-null object
Location               53515 non-null object
Distance               52304 non-null float64
Owner Type             53515 non-null object
manufacture_year       53515 non-null int64
Age of car             53515 non-null int64
engine_displacement    53515 non-null int64
engine_power           52076 non-null float64
body_type              4136 non-null object
Vroom Audit Rating     53515 non-null int64
transmission           53515 non-null object
door_count             53515 non-null object
seat_count             53515 non-null object
fuel_type              53515 non-null object
Price                  53515 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(5), object(9)
```

The columns door_count and seat_count contain the terms 'None' which I want to replace with numerical values. My algorithm:
If for a particular Maker, model combination the door_count is 'None', then fill it with the median value of the of door_count of the Maker, model combination.
Eg., if Maker is Skoda, and model is Octavia, the algorithm would find the median of the door_count and fill the none value.

Here is the code snippet which I have tried to implement:

```
def find_door_count(Maker, model):
    car_df_temp = car_df[car_df['door_count']!='None']
    car_df_temp['door_count'] = car_df_temp['door_count'].astype('int64')
    ans = car_df_temp[(car_df_temp['Maker']==Maker) & (car_df_temp['model']==model)]['door_count'].median()
    return ans

car_df['door_count'].apply(lambda row: find_door_count(row['Maker'], row['model']))
```

On running the above snippet, I get the following error:

----> 1 car_df['door_count'].apply(lambda row: find_door_count(row['Maker'], row['model']))

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Make a small example dataset and add an expected output so we can visually see what you want to do. Ask about your problem and we can provide a solution, not why your code is not working, check [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: But this might help your problem, although your code is not the pandas way to solve this: `car_df_temp['door_count'] = car_df_temp['door_count'].astype(int)`. So just `int` instead of `'int64'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you select the column `door_count` in `car_df` with the statement `car_df['door_count']`, your code is calling [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).  The function passed to this method takes either a Series representing the column of the DataFrame, or a single value, not a row of the DataFrame as you might think.

I suggest you rethink how you want to solve this problem.  Pandas is optimized to perform column-wise operations, not to iterate over rows.  You state you want to do the following:

1. Calculate the median number of doors for a given make and model.
2. Fill the null door values in your data set with that median.

The first step, in Pandas, is a [`groupby` followed by a `transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation): you are looking to "group by" `Maker` and `Model`, then create a replacement value for `door_count` that is a "transformation" of that column in those groups.  Assuming the values of 'door_count' are of type `float`, here is what it looks like in code:

```
car_df['median_door_counts'] = car_df.groupby(['Maker', 'Model'])['door_count'].transform('median')  # perform the transformation
```

Here is an example of this in action:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

car_df = pd.DataFrame({"Maker": ["Ford", "Tesla", "GM"] * 4,
                       "Model": ["Pinto", "S", "Sierra", "Fiesta", "X", "Volt"] * 2, 
                       "door_count": np.random.randint(0, 4, size=12, dtype="float")})

car_df['door_count'] = car_df['door_count'].astype(float)     # allow door_count to be nan
car_df.loc[car_df['door_count'] == 0, 'door_count'] = np.nan  # generate some nans

car_df['median_door_counts'] = car_df.groupby(['Maker', 'Model'])['door_count'].transform('median')
print(car_df)
#     Maker   Model  door_count  median_door_counts
# 0    Ford   Pinto         NaN                 NaN
# 1   Tesla       S         2.0                 2.0
# 2      GM  Sierra         2.0                 2.0
# 3    Ford  Fiesta         2.0                 2.0
# 4   Tesla       X         2.0                 2.5
# 5      GM    Volt         1.0                 1.0
# 6    Ford   Pinto         NaN                 NaN
# 7   Tesla       S         NaN                 2.0
# 8      GM  Sierra         NaN                 2.0
# 9    Ford  Fiesta         2.0                 2.0
# 10  Tesla       X         3.0                 2.5
# 11     GM    Volt         1.0                 1.0
```

You should look up [`Series.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.median.html) and check out the default arguments to see why this works and why I transformed the column to float values.  Also, note that all the values of `door_count` are missing for the Ford Pinto, so their median value is also missing.

Now that these medians are a column in the DataFrame, so you can perform the replacement operation as you see fit using selection logic:

```
null_door = car_df['door_count'].isnull()  # or whatever logic you want
car_df.loc[null_door, 'door_count'] = car_df.loc[null_door, 'median_door_counts']
```

The result on the sample data I generated:

```
print(car_df)
#     Maker   Model  door_count  median_door_counts
# 0    Ford   Pinto         NaN                 NaN
# 1   Tesla       S         2.0                 2.0
# 2      GM  Sierra         2.0                 2.0
# 3    Ford  Fiesta         2.0                 2.0
# 4   Tesla       X         2.0                 2.5
# 5      GM    Volt         1.0                 1.0
# 6    Ford   Pinto         NaN                 NaN
# 7   Tesla       S         2.0                 2.0
# 8      GM  Sierra         2.0                 2.0
# 9    Ford  Fiesta         2.0                 2.0
# 10  Tesla       X         3.0                 2.5
# 11     GM    Volt         1.0                 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what error says

```
data[1]  #this will work 
data['string'] #this will not work
```